# How to handle this with async Ajax request and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

So this function getXmlData() get's called across the app who's main responsibility is to return xml to and save it to a variable, in this example below it is 'test'

```
    var test = getXmlData();

    function getXmlData() {
           queryData(getData);
    }

   function getData(xml) {
        if (xml) {
           return xml;  
        }
    }

    function queryData(callback){

        $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/JSON",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(xml){
               callback(xml);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Error!!");
            }
        })
    }
```

Now we know that here parent function will return before the callback is executed and so 'test' variable will be undefined.
I'm not sure how can I handle this situation here. I'm tied to using this structure. I basically want getXmlData to return xml that is being returned in queryData. Suggestions!?

Comment: you can never get a synchronous result once asynchronous code is involved, no matter how abstracted you make the request (calling a function which calls a function which calls an asynchronous function that calls the success callback which calls your callback in your case)

Comment: you could `var test;
    function getXmlData() {
           test = queryData(getData);
    }` however you can never know when `test` is populated - because asynchronism is like a virus, once used, you can never get a synchronous result

Comment: @JaromandaX `asynchronism is like a virus`, a bit harsh.. :)  I'd say it's like when you first drive an automatic, after years of using a manual, you nearly go through the front windscreen, but after a while you start to like it, with the bonus of not been able to stall.

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand, guess I will have to go asynchronous or change some structure.

Comment: I didn't mean it in a negative context - just the infectious nature of asynchronism :p

Comment: @JaromandaX `infectious nature`, nice one.. :)